# how to find even numbers?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to find even numbers from 0 to 100 but it is not working. even it not showing any error. can anyone help me to figure out?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>        
var x = 1;
        while (x <= 100) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                console.log(x);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            x++;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It breaks out of your `while` loop as soon as `x % 2 == 0` is false, which is the case for `x = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(let x =0; x<=100; x+=2){
console.log(x);
}
```

I wouldn't check for even numbers. It's easier to just start by 0 and add 2 each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
function printEven() {
   for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      if(i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: no problem! i would appreciate if you can mark it as useful and approve the answer (:

Comment: lol I don't think you want him to flag the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
    var x = 1;
        while (x <= 100) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                console.log(x);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            x++;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It stops after the firs round, because "if (x % 2 == 0)" does not match and else is a "break"

Answer (score 0):

It breaks out of your while loop like ivar said

```
    while (x <= 100) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            console.log(x);
        }
        x++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as a one liner:

```js
Array(50).fill().map((_, i) => i*2+2).forEach((v) => console.log(v))

// Alternatives
console.log(  Array(50).fill().map((_, i) => i*2+2)  )
console.log(  [...Array(50).keys()].map(i => i*2+2)  )
console.log(  [...Array(50)].map((_, i) => i*2+2)    )
console.log(  Array.from(Array(50), (_, i) => i*2+2) )
```

jk

Comment: I like your approach

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, index) => (index + 1) * 2).forEach((val) => console.log(val))` would omit the `fill`.